# Quick way to find what thread asserted in gdb?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, gdb

When my Cocoa app hits an assertion in the code, gdb gives me a prompt as expected, but it's never (ok, rarely) in the right thread.

I know I can use Xcode's GUI debugger and it makes it a little less painful, but I'm thinking there has to be a gdb command line trick I don't know.

Is there an easier way of finding the thread that asserted other than changing to each thread and issuing `where`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`(gdb) thread apply all bt`

Comment: This is what I do now. The problem with this is that it only shows the last stack frame which isn't always very helpful so you end up doing a where on each one.

Comment: That shows you full stack traces of all running threads so you easily see which one has asserted. I think you are mixing this with 'info threads'.

Comment: That is only a workaround. And not very comfortable when you have many threads.

Comment: Who said this is going to be comfortable :)

Answer (score 3):

Nikolai suggested 'thread apply all bt'.  There's also 'info threads' which can sometimes help you find the one you want with less verbosity.

Suppose, 'info threads' doesn't show what you want, and you are forced to comb through the stacktraces for all threads.  That can be painful if your process has many threads (this can easily be hundreds in some programs).  You can limit the number of frames shown per thread to something more tractable (say 5 frames)

```
(gdb) thread apply all where 5
```

But even this can be difficult to comb through, since you may have to keep hitting the pager prompt looking for what you want, and can miss your target easily.  When that's the case, I've found the combination of enabling logging and crippling the pager very helpful

```
(gdb) set height 10000
(gdb) set logging on
(gdb) thread apply all where 5
(gdb) shell
```

Now examine gdb.txt and find your thread.