# how to get the thread which asserted in gdb

Tags: xcode, gdb

When some assert() fails, gdb breaks but doesn't show the aborting thread. In case of a signal (like a segfault), it works fine. Is there an easy way to know what threads has just aborted?

Esp., I am using Xcode here.

Comment: dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1647809/quick-way-to-find-what-thread-asserted-in-gdb

Comment: The author of this question accepted an answer which is absolutely no solution for me. (And which is also not really an answer to the question.)

Comment: +1, same problem here (also, please include in your answers with which programming languages the solution works).

Answer (score 0):

You can write your own `assert` marco which sends `SIGSEGV` instead of `SIGABRT`.

```
#define assert(check) do { if(!(check)) kill (getpid(), SIGSEGV); } while(0)
```